# Jolt - Split objects on the basis of input array

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

In Jolt, I want to modify my objects on the basis of items inside the address array. The object should split into the multiple objects on the basis of items of the array. Please assist in solving this. Thankyou.

Input:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "dept": "IT",
    "address": [
      "Austria",
      "India",
      "US"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Shelly",
    "dept": "Pharma",
    "address": [
      "Finland",
      "UK"
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected output:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "dept": "IT",
    "address": "Austria"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "dept": "IT",
    "address": "India"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "dept": "IT",
    "address": "US"
  },
  {
    "name": "Shelly",
    "dept": "Pharma",
    "address": "Finland"
  },
  {
    "name": "Shelly",
    "dept": "Pharma",
    "address": "UK"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following **shift** transformation spec in which the returned attributes are tiled based on the two groupings :

1. the indexes of the objects within the main array,
2. the indexes of the **`address`** array

such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "address": {
          "*": {
            "@2,name": "&3.&1.name", // go 2 levels up the tree to grab the related value
            "@2,dept": "&3.&1.dept",
            "@": "&3.&1.&2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Hi @Nishu , welcome to community.